# R Sweave doesn't generate the correct output from R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sweave

I have made a R Shiny App where after some statistical tests, a pdf-report is generated with knit2pdf and R Sweave.
The problem is that the R Sweave doesn't print the correct values of tests, after the application is used several times before. In other words, the R Sweave "save" some values when the app is used before, and then doesn't print the correct values from the R Shiny App.

Some example is: [Shiny ex-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhV1.png)[Pdf ex-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Ct9.png)[Shiny ex-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhq4Z.png)[Pdf ex-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Getg.png)

I have set the working directory (where the R Sweave file is) in the server file, thinking that after saving the first pdf report (after using the app) the directory is changing and the app doesn't recognize the files (I hope I explained well).

I will attach the code from server with knit2pdf:

```
output$report = downloadHandler(
    filename = 'myreport.pdf',

    content = function(file) {
      
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "input.Rnw")
      file.copy("input.Rnw", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      out = knit2pdf(tempReport, clean = TRUE)
      file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
    },

    contentType = 'application/pdf'
  )
```

I don't know what to upload here to be more specific, but I'm waiting for indications, and I will edit my question.

EDIT-The code associated with the pictures::

The server:

```
 Reg.model <- reactive({
    print(input$Select)
    if (is.null(input$Txdef)){
      return(NULL)
    }
      
    switch(input$Txdef,
           dNone = { depvar = input$DepVar})
           
    indepvar = NULL
    if (!is.null(input$IndepVar)){
      indepvar = c(indepvar, input$IndepVar)
    }
    
    if (!is.null(indepvar)){
      if (!is.null(input$Select) && any(input$Select == "NoIntercept")){
        model = paste(depvar,paste("-1+",paste(indepvar,collapse = "+"),sep = ""),sep="~")
      }
      else  {
        model = paste(depvar,paste(indepvar,collapse = "+"),sep = "~")
      }
      return(model)
    }
    else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })   
  
  
  Reg.fit = reactive({
    if (is.null(input$IndepVar)){
      return(NULL)
    }
      
    
    data1 = datos()
    if (input$Txdef == "dlog"){
      if (nrow(data1[data1[input$DepVar] <= 0,]) > 0){
        data1[data1[input$DepVar] <=0,input$DepVar] = 1e-5}
    }
    #data1[input$IndepVar] = lapply(data1[input$IndepVar],as.factor)
    data1[input$DepVar] = lapply(data1[input$DepVar],as.numeric)
    #e1 = paste(input$DepVar,paste(input$IndepVar,collapse = "+"),sep = "~")
    e1 = Reg.model()
    
    fit = lm(formula(e1),data = data1)
    return(fit)
    saveRDS(fit, "Model.rds")
  }
  )  
   AdjustedDetermination=reactive({
    
     Rajustado <- summary(Reg.fit())$adj.r.squared
    
    paste("Whit the current model you got an adjusted R squared of",format(round(Rajustado,2),nsmall=2), ".")
  })
  
  output$AdjustedDetermination <- renderText({
        AdjustedDetermination()
  })
  
  testad=reactive({
    if (is.null(input$Norm)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    if(input$Norm == 2 | input$Norm==1){
      ad.test(Reg.fit()$residuals)
    }
  })
  
  output$ad=renderPrint({
    testad()
  })
  
  concad=reactive({
    if(testad()$p.value < 0.05){paste("The normality condition is not met according to Anderson-Darling test, pvalue = ",format(round(testad()$p.value,2),nsmall=2))}else{paste("The errors are normally distributed according to Anderson-Darling test, pvalue =",format(round(testad()$p.value,2),nsmall=2))}
    
  })
```

The R Sweave:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em,frame=single}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em,frame=single}

\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
options(width=200)
@

<<setup, cache = FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(width=200)
@

<<Vif,echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
options(digits=4)
print(AdjustedDetermination())
@

<<nor,echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
options(digits=2)
print(testad())
@
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but I can't imagine an instance where setting the working directory in the server code would be a good thing. `downloadHandler` won't do anything with the working directory.

Comment: The code if very long, but I can put some, associated with the pictures. :) check my edit.