# R Shiny-The correct output is not printed in R Sweave Report

Tags: r, shiny, sweave

Some weeks ago I asked:[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389201/r-sweave-doesnt-generate-the-correct-output-from-r-shiny?noredirect=1#comment120865680_68389201), which unfortunately did not received any answer.

After recommendation, I tried to make a MRE and I hope that in this way everything will be much clear.

The problem is again, the conclusion of the model: AIC, VIF, Determination and AdjustedDetermination, are not printed correctly after multiple runs.

The first run of the application is ok, the report is 1:1 as in R Shiny App, but after, to second run (with another regression, variables etc), in report is printed again, the first run.

I hope this is more clear. For images you can check the hyperlink above,

Thanks in advance!

I can not provide the dataset, but you can try with any dataset on which the linear regression works.

R Shiny App:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
library(nortest)
library(tseries)
library(RcmdrMisc)
library(lmtest)
library(readxl)
library(tseries)
library(dplyr)
library(nlme)
library(openxlsx)
library(skedastic)
library(knitr)
library(nnet)
library(reshape)
library(crunch)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                   
                   titlePanel("Model Validation"),
                   navbarPage("Let's get started",
                              tabPanel(icon("home"),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       hr(),
                                       tags$style(".fa-database {color:#E87722}"),
                                       h3(p(em("Dataset "),icon("database",lib = "font-awesome"),style="color:black;text-align:center")),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       fileInput("uploaded_file", "Choose Excel File",
                                                 multiple = TRUE,
                                                 accept = c("text/csv",
                                                            "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                            ".xlsx")),
                                       uiOutput("dropdownUI"),
                                       
                                       #tableOutput("RawData"),
                                       uiOutput("checkbox"),
                                       uiOutput("ceckbox2"),
                                       uiOutput("ceckbox3"),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       fluidRow(column(DT::dataTableOutput("RawData"),
                                                       width = 12)),
                                       hr(),
                                       
                                       
                                       #radioButtons('report_format', 'Generate report:', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
                                       downloadButton(outputId = "report", label = "Download report"),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                              ),
                              
                              
                              
                              tabPanel("Model Replication",
                                       
                                       #uiOutput("Regvariable"),
                                       
                                       textOutput('textReg'),
                                       uiOutput("varReg"),
                                       p(strong('Model output',style="color:blue")),
                                       fluidRow(
                                         column(verbatimTextOutput("SummaryReg"),
                                                br(),width = 6),
                                         column(br(),
                                                
                                                
                                                textOutput("Determination"),
                                                
                                                br(),
                                                textOutput("AdjustedDetermination"),
                                                br(),width = 6,style="background-color:lavender;border-left:8px solid blue")
                                         
                                       ),p(strong('AIC',style="color:blue")),
                                       fluidRow(column(verbatimTextOutput("AIC"),width=7)),
                                       
                                       p(strong('Variance inflation factor',style="color:blue")),
                                       fluidRow(column(verbatimTextOutput("VIF"),width=7),
                                                column(width=1),
                                                column(br(),
                                                       br(),textOutput("Alarm"),
                                                       br(),
                                                       br(),width = 4,style="background-color:  #A8D9F3;border-left:8px solid blue;border-top: 1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black")),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       mainPanel()
                                       
                                       
                              ),
                              
                              tabPanel("Model Validation",
                                       
                                       fluidRow(column(width=2),
                                                column(
                                                  h4(p("Assumptions for model residuals",style="color:black;text-align:center")),
                                                  width=8,style="background-color:lavender;border-radius: 10px")),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                     
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       hr(),
                                       
                                       
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         tabPanel("Normality",
                                                  
                                                  br(),
                                                  navlistPanel(widths=c(2,9),fluid = T,well = T,
                                                               
                                                               
                                                               
                                                               
                                                               tabPanel("Analytical test",
                                                                        
                                                                        uiOutput("Norm"),
                                                                        fluidRow(
                                                                          column( verbatimTextOutput("Prueba2"),
                                                                                  br(),width = 6),
                                                                          column(br(),
                                                                                 
                                                                                 
                                                                                 textOutput("Conclusion12"),
                                                                                 
                                                                                 
                                                                                 br(),width = 6,style="background-color:lavender;border-left:8px solid blue")
                                                                          
                                                                        )
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                               ))))
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                        
                                         
                                        
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                       ))
                              
                              
                   )
    ,
    server = function(input, output){
    #Dataset  
      Workbook <- eventReactive(input$uploaded_file, {
        loadWorkbook(input$uploaded_file$datapath)
      })
      
      Sheets <- eventReactive(Workbook(), {
        names(Workbook())
      })
      
      output$dropdownUI <- renderUI({
        req(Sheets())
        selectInput("sheet", "Choose a sheet", Sheets())
      })
      
      datos <- eventReactive(input$sheet, {
        read.xlsx(Workbook(), sheet = input$sheet)
      })
      
      df_sel <- reactive({
        req(input$y)
        req(input$x1)
        req(input$x2)
        df_sel <- datos() %>% select(input$y,input$x1,input$x2)
      })
      
      #Regression
      output$Regvariable = renderUI({
        
        if (is.null(datos())){
          return(NULL)}
        variables = colnames(datos())
        checkboxGroupInput("Regvariable", "Choose Variables for regression", variables,selected = variables[[1]])
      })
      
      
      textReg=reactive({
        paste("Model(e1):", Reg.model(),sep = " ")
      })
      
      
      
      output$textReg = renderText({
        textReg()
      })
      
      
      output$varReg = renderUI({
        if (is.null(datos())){
          return(NULL)}
        variables = colnames(datos())
        div(class = "row-fluid",
            div(class="span2",selectInput("DepVar", strong("Dependent Variable",style = "color:red"),variables)),
            div(class="span2",checkboxGroupInput("Select", strong("Options",style = "color:blue"),c("No Intercept Model" = "NoIntercept"))),
            #div(class="span1",checkboxInput("Nointercept", "No Intercept Model", FALSE)),
            div(class="span1",checkboxGroupInput("IndepVar", strong("Indep Vars",style = "color:green"), variables,selected = variables[[2]])),
            div(class="span1",radioButtons("Txdef", strong("Transform Dep Var",style = "color:green"),c(None = "dNone",Log= "dlog", Sqrt = "dsqrt",Square = "dsq",
                                                                                                        Cube = "dcube", Exponential = "dexp")))
        )
      })
      
      Reg.model <- reactive({
        print(input$Select)
        if (is.null(input$Txdef)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        switch(input$Txdef,
               dNone = { depvar = input$DepVar})
        
        indepvar = NULL
        if (!is.null(input$IndepVar)){
          indepvar = c(indepvar, input$IndepVar)
        }
        
        if (!is.null(indepvar)){
          if (!is.null(input$Select) && any(input$Select == "NoIntercept")){
            model = paste(depvar,paste("-1+",paste(indepvar,collapse = "+"),sep = ""),sep="~")
          }
          else  {
            model = paste(depvar,paste(indepvar,collapse = "+"),sep = "~")
          }
          return(model)
        }
        else {
          return(NULL)
        }
      })   
      
      
      Reg.fit = reactive({
        if (is.null(input$IndepVar)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        
        data1 = datos()
        if (input$Txdef == "dlog"){
          if (nrow(data1[data1[input$DepVar] <= 0,]) > 0){
            data1[data1[input$DepVar] <=0,input$DepVar] = 1e-5}
        }
        #data1[input$IndepVar] = lapply(data1[input$IndepVar],as.factor)
        data1[input$DepVar] = lapply(data1[input$DepVar],as.numeric)
        #e1 = paste(input$DepVar,paste(input$IndepVar,collapse = "+"),sep = "~")
        e1 = Reg.model()
        
        fit = lm(formula(e1),data = data1)
        return(fit)
        saveRDS(fit, "Model.rds")
      }
      )  
      
      
      SummaryReg=reactive({
        if (is.null(datos()))
          return(NULL)
        if (is.null(input$IndepVar))
          return(NULL)
        summary(Reg.fit())
      })
      
      output$SummaryReg <- renderPrint({
        SummaryReg()
      })
      
      VIF=reactive({
        
        if(length(Reg.fit()$coefficients)<2){
          mensaje="The model must have at least two explanatory variables to execute this function"
          mensaje
        }
        else
        {
          vif(Reg.fit())
        }
        
      })
      
      
      output$VIF <- renderPrint({
        VIF()
      })
      
      aic=reactive({
        AIC(Reg.fit())
      })
      
      output$AIC=renderPrint({
        aic()
      })
      Alarm=reactive({
        
        if(length(Reg.fit()$coefficients)<=2){
        paste("The model does not has enough independent variables")
          
        }
        else
        {
          listadevifs <- vif(Reg.fit())
          
          mensaje="There are no multicollinearity problems"
          nombres <- vector(mode = "numeric",length = 7)
          
          for(i in 1:length(listadevifs)){
            
            if(listadevifs[[i]]>5){
              
              mensaje="There are multicollinearity problems in the following variables:"
              nombres[i] = i
            }
          }
          
          variablesconproblemas <- paste(names(listadevifs[nombres]),collapse = ", ")
          
          
          if(nombres[1]==0 & nombres[2]==0 & nombres[3]==0 & nombres[4]==0 & nombres[5]==0 & nombres[6]==0 & nombres[7]==0){
            mensaje
          }
          else
          {
            paste(mensaje,variablesconproblemas,". You should keep only one of these.") 
          }
        }
        
      })
      output$Alarm <- renderText({
        
        Alarm()
        
      })
      Determination=reactive({
        valoresp <- summary(Reg.fit())$coefficients[,4]
        
        mensaje1 = "All the model parameters are significant for a confidence level of 95%"
        nombresbetas <- vector(mode = "numeric",length = 6)
        
        for(i in 1:length(valoresp)){
          
          if(valoresp[[i]]>0.05){
            mensaje1="There are parameters which are not significant, these parameters correspond to:"
            nombresbetas[i]=i
          }
        }
        
        betasnosignificativos <- paste(names(valoresp[nombresbetas]),collapse = ", ")
        paste(mensaje1, betasnosignificativos)
      })
      
      
      output$Determination <- renderText({
        Determination()
      })
      
      
      AdjustedDetermination=reactive({
        
        Rajustado <- summary(Reg.fit())$adj.r.squared
        
        paste("With the current model you got an adjusted R squared of",format(round(Rajustado,2),nsmall=2), ".")
      })
      
      
      
      output$AdjustedDetermination <- renderText({
        AdjustedDetermination()
      })
      
      #Normality
      
      output$Norm = renderUI({
        checkboxGroupInput("Norm", "Choose test the verify the normality of the residuals", choices=c("Shapiro-Wilk"=1,"Anderson-Darling"=2,"Cramer-von Mises"=3,"Kolmogorov-Smirnov"=4,"Jarque-Bera"=5))
      })
      
      testanalitico2 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$Norm)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        if(input$Norm == 1){
          
          shapiro.test(Reg.fit()$residuals)
          
        }
      })
      
      
      output$Prueba2 <- renderPrint({
        
        testanalitico2()
        
      })
      
      concprueba2=reactive({
        if(testanalitico2()$p.value < 0.05){paste("The normality condition is not met according to Shapiro-Wilk test, pvalue = ",format(round(testanalitico2()$p.value,2),nsmall=2))}else{paste("The errors are normally distributed according to Shapiro-Wilk test, pvalue =",format(round(testanalitico2()$p.value,2),nsmall=2))}
        
      })
      
      output$Conclusion12 <- renderText({
        concprueba2()
      })
      
      
      output$report = downloadHandler(
        filename = 'myreport.pdf',
        
        content = function(file) {
          out = knit2pdf('stackoverflow.Rnw', clean = TRUE)
          file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
        },
        
        contentType = 'application/pdf'
      )
      
    }
  )
)
```

R Sweave:

```
\documentclass{article}



\title{ Model Replication and Validation Report}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

<<setup, cache = FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(width=200)
@

<<Concstat,echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
options(digits=2)
@

\section{Regression Model}

Replication of the regression model:

<<Model,echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(comment="", message=FALSE,tidy.opts=list(keep.blank.line=TRUE, width.cutoff=120),options(width=100), cache=TRUE,fig.align='center',fig.height=6, fig.width=10,fig.path='figure/beamer-',fig.show='hold',size='footnotesize', cache=TRUE)

print(textReg())
print(Reg.model())

print(SummaryReg())
@

Conclusion of the model:

 AIC:
<<echo=FALSE>>=
print(aic())

@

VIF:

<<echo=FALSE>>=
print(VIF())

@

Parameters:
<<echo=FALSE>>=
print( Determination())
 
@

Adjusted R Squared:
<<Vif,echo=FALSE>>=


 print(AdjustedDetermination())
@

After replication, we begin the model validation, testing the assumptions of linear model.

\subsection{Normality of the residuals}

<<nor,echo=FALSE>>=

print(testanalitico2())
print( concprueba2())
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: With a problem like this, unless you provide you *complete* code AND provide a detailed description of the steps necessary to reproduce your problem, it is very unlikely we will be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that the code is very long, and in my last question( posted in the hyperlink),  are the lines which give the error. What code should I post to be more reliable?

Comment: Then you need to invest some time in producing a minimal repordicible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Giving us the lines that generate the error may not be helpful because the *cause* of the error is often elsewhere.   This is the case here, where the error doesn't occur first time round. **You need to help us help you.**  And besides, I often find that the effort in producing a MRE lets me identify the problem and solve it myself.