# R Shiny:The correct output is not printed in R Sweave Report

Tags: r, shiny, sweave

as my last 2 questions:  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389201/r-sweave-doesnt-generate-the-correct-output-from-r-shiny) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737477/r-shiny-the-correct-output-is-not-printed-in-r-sweave-report), and after the last advice, I tried to make an MRE to summarize the problem- after some runs, even if in R Shiny App the output is printed correct, in R Sweave Report is printed one of the past runs, or, even is not printed correct from the first run of the APP.

I can not provide the dataset, but you can use any kind of data which work for linear regression analysis.

The functions with problems in report are `VIF()`, `aic()`, `Determination()`, `AdjustedDetermination()` , `testanalitico2()` and  `concprueba2()`.

Thanks in advance!

R Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(car)
library(lmtest)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(crunch)
setwd("C:/Users/mtorsan/Documents/APP")

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                   
                   titlePanel("Model Validation"),
                   navbarPage("Let's get started",
                              tabPanel(icon("home"),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       hr(),
                                       tags$style(".fa-database {color:#E87722}"),
                                       h3(p(em("Dataset "),icon("database",lib = "font-awesome"),style="color:black;text-align:center")),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       fileInput("uploaded_file", "Choose Excel File",
                                                 multiple = TRUE,
                                                 accept = c("text/csv",
                                                            "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                            ".xlsx")),
                                       uiOutput("dropdownUI"),
                                       
                                       #tableOutput("RawData"),
                                       uiOutput("checkbox"),
                                       uiOutput("ceckbox2"),
                                       uiOutput("ceckbox3"),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       fluidRow(column(DT::dataTableOutput("RawData"),
                                                       width = 12)),
                                       hr(),
                                       
                                       
                                       #radioButtons('report_format', 'Generate report:', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
                                       downloadButton(outputId = "report", label = "Download report"),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                              ),
                              
                              
                              
                              tabPanel("Model Replication",
                                       
                                       #uiOutput("Regvariable"),
                                       
                                       textOutput('textReg'),
                                       uiOutput("varReg"),
                                       p(strong('Model output',style="color:blue")),
                                       fluidRow(
                                         column(verbatimTextOutput("SummaryReg"),
                                                br(),width = 6),
                                         column(br(),
                                                
                                                
                                                textOutput("Determination"),
                                                
                                                br(),
                                                textOutput("AdjustedDetermination"),
                                                br(),width = 6,style="background-color:lavender;border-left:8px solid blue")
                                         
                                       ),p(strong('AIC',style="color:blue")),
                                       fluidRow(column(verbatimTextOutput("AIC"),width=7)),
                                       
                                       p(strong('Variance inflation factor',style="color:blue")),
                                       fluidRow(column(verbatimTextOutput("VIF"),width=7),
                                                column(width=1),
                                                column(br(),
                                                       br(),textOutput("Alarm"),
                                                       br(),
                                                       br(),width = 4,style="background-color:  #A8D9F3;border-left:8px solid blue;border-top: 1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black")),
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                       mainPanel()
                                       
                                       
                              ),
                              
                              tabPanel("Model Validation",
                                       
                                       fluidRow(column(width=2),
                                                column(
                                                  h4(p("Assumptions for model residuals",style="color:black;text-align:center")),
                                                  width=8,style="background-color:lavender;border-radius: 10px")),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                     
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       hr(),
                                       
                                       
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         tabPanel("Normality",
                                                  
                                                  br(),
                                                  navlistPanel(widths=c(2,9),fluid = T,well = T,
                                                               
                                                               
                                                               
                                                               
                                                               tabPanel("Analytical test",
                                                                        
                                                                        uiOutput("Norm"),
                                                                        fluidRow(
                                                                          column( verbatimTextOutput("Prueba2"),
                                                                                  br(),width = 6),
                                                                          column(br(),
                                                                                 
                                                                                 
                                                                                 textOutput("Conclusion12"),
                                                                                 
                                                                                 
                                                                                 br(),width = 6,style="background-color:lavender;border-left:8px solid blue")
                                                                          
                                                                        )
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                               ))))
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                        
                                         
                                        
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                       ))
                              
                              
                   )
    ,
    server = function(input, output){
    #Dataset  
      Workbook <- eventReactive(input$uploaded_file, {
        loadWorkbook(input$uploaded_file$datapath)
      })
      
      Sheets <- eventReactive(Workbook(), {
        names(Workbook())
      })
      
      output$dropdownUI <- renderUI({
        req(Sheets())
        selectInput("sheet", "Choose a sheet", Sheets())
      })
      
      datos <- eventReactive(input$sheet, {
        read.xlsx(Workbook(), sheet = input$sheet)
      })
      
      df_sel <- reactive({
        req(input$y)
        req(input$x1)
        req(input$x2)
        df_sel <- datos() %>% select(input$y,input$x1,input$x2)
      })
      
      #Regression
      output$Regvariable = renderUI({
        
        if (is.null(datos())){
          return(NULL)}
        variables = colnames(datos())
        checkboxGroupInput("Regvariable", "Choose Variables for regression", variables,selected = variables[[1]])
      })
      
      
      textReg=reactive({
        paste("Model(e1):", Reg.model(),sep = " ")
      })
      
      
      
      output$textReg = renderText({
        textReg()
      })
      
      
      output$varReg = renderUI({
        if (is.null(datos())){
          return(NULL)}
        variables = colnames(datos())
        div(class = "row-fluid",
            div(class="span2",selectInput("DepVar", strong("Dependent Variable",style = "color:red"),variables)),
            div(class="span2",checkboxGroupInput("Select", strong("Options",style = "color:blue"),c("No Intercept Model" = "NoIntercept"))),
            #div(class="span1",checkboxInput("Nointercept", "No Intercept Model", FALSE)),
            div(class="span1",checkboxGroupInput("IndepVar", strong("Indep Vars",style = "color:green"), variables,selected = variables[[2]])),
            div(class="span1",radioButtons("Txdef", strong("Transform Dep Var",style = "color:green"),c(None = "dNone",Log= "dlog", Sqrt = "dsqrt",Square = "dsq",
                                                                                                        Cube = "dcube", Exponential = "dexp")))
        )
      })
      
      Reg.model <- reactive({
        print(input$Select)
        if (is.null(input$Txdef)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        switch(input$Txdef,
               dNone = { depvar = input$DepVar})
        
        indepvar = NULL
        if (!is.null(input$IndepVar)){
          indepvar = c(indepvar, input$IndepVar)
        }
        
        if (!is.null(indepvar)){
          if (!is.null(input$Select) && any(input$Select == "NoIntercept")){
            model = paste(depvar,paste("-1+",paste(indepvar,collapse = "+"),sep = ""),sep="~")
          }
          else  {
            model = paste(depvar,paste(indepvar,collapse = "+"),sep = "~")
          }
          return(model)
        }
        else {
          return(NULL)
        }
      })   
      
      
      Reg.fit = reactive({
        if (is.null(input$IndepVar)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        
        data1 = datos()
        if (input$Txdef == "dlog"){
          if (nrow(data1[data1[input$DepVar] <= 0,]) > 0){
            data1[data1[input$DepVar] <=0,input$DepVar] = 1e-5}
        }
        #data1[input$IndepVar] = lapply(data1[input$IndepVar],as.factor)
        data1[input$DepVar] = lapply(data1[input$DepVar],as.numeric)
        #e1 = paste(input$DepVar,paste(input$IndepVar,collapse = "+"),sep = "~")
        e1 = Reg.model()
        
        fit = lm(formula(e1),data = data1)
        return(fit)
        saveRDS(fit, "Model.rds")
      }
      )  
      
      
      SummaryReg=reactive({
        if (is.null(datos()))
          return(NULL)
        if (is.null(input$IndepVar))
          return(NULL)
        summary(Reg.fit())
      })
      
      output$SummaryReg <- renderPrint({
        SummaryReg()
      })
      
      VIF=reactive({
        
        if(length(Reg.fit()$coefficients)<2){
          mensaje="The model must have at least two explanatory variables to execute this function"
          mensaje
        }
        else
        {
          vif(Reg.fit())
        }
        
      })
      
      
      output$VIF <- renderPrint({
        VIF()
      })
      
      aic=reactive({
        AIC(Reg.fit())
      })
      
      output$AIC=renderPrint({
        aic()
      })
      Alarm=reactive({
        
        if(length(Reg.fit()$coefficients)<=2){
        paste("The model does not has enough independent variables")
          
        }
        else
        {
          listadevifs <- vif(Reg.fit())
          
          mensaje="There are no multicollinearity problems"
          nombres <- vector(mode = "numeric",length = 7)
          
          for(i in 1:length(listadevifs)){
            
            if(listadevifs[[i]]>5){
              
              mensaje="There are multicollinearity problems in the following variables:"
              nombres[i] = i
            }
          }
          
          variablesconproblemas <- paste(names(listadevifs[nombres]),collapse = ", ")
          
          
          if(nombres[1]==0 & nombres[2]==0 & nombres[3]==0 & nombres[4]==0 & nombres[5]==0 & nombres[6]==0 & nombres[7]==0){
            mensaje
          }
          else
          {
            paste(mensaje,variablesconproblemas,". You should keep only one of these.") 
          }
        }
        
      })
      output$Alarm <- renderText({
        
        Alarm()
        
      })
      Determination=reactive({
        valoresp <- summary(Reg.fit())$coefficients[,4]
        
        mensaje1 = "All the model parameters are significant for a confidence level of 95%"
        nombresbetas <- vector(mode = "numeric",length = 6)
        
        for(i in 1:length(valoresp)){
          
          if(valoresp[[i]]>0.05){
            mensaje1="There are parameters which are not significant, these parameters correspond to:"
            nombresbetas[i]=i
          }
        }
        
        betasnosignificativos <- paste(names(valoresp[nombresbetas]),collapse = ", ")
        paste(mensaje1, betasnosignificativos)
      })
      
      
      output$Determination <- renderText({
        Determination()
      })
      
      
      AdjustedDetermination=reactive({
        
        Rajustado <- summary(Reg.fit())$adj.r.squared
        
        paste("With the current model you got an adjusted R squared of",format(round(Rajustado,2),nsmall=2), ".")
      })
      
      
      
      output$AdjustedDetermination <- renderText({
        AdjustedDetermination()
      })
      
      #Normality
      
      output$Norm = renderUI({
        checkboxGroupInput("Norm", "Choose test the verify the normality of the residuals", choices=c("Shapiro-Wilk"=1,"Anderson-Darling"=2,"Cramer-von Mises"=3,"Kolmogorov-Smirnov"=4,"Jarque-Bera"=5))
      })
      
      testanalitico2 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$Norm)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        if(input$Norm == 1){
          
          shapiro.test(Reg.fit()$residuals)
          
        }
      })
      
      
      output$Prueba2 <- renderPrint({
        
        testanalitico2()
        
      })
      
      concprueba2=reactive({
        if(testanalitico2()$p.value < 0.05){paste("The normality condition is not met according to Shapiro-Wilk test, pvalue = ",format(round(testanalitico2()$p.value,2),nsmall=2))}else{paste("The errors are normally distributed according to Shapiro-Wilk test, pvalue =",format(round(testanalitico2()$p.value,2),nsmall=2))}
        
      })
      
      output$Conclusion12 <- renderText({
        concprueba2()
      })
      
      
      output$report = downloadHandler(
        filename = 'myreport.pdf',
        
        content = function(file) {
          
          tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "sf.Rnw")
          file.copy("sf.Rnw", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
          
          out = knit2pdf(tempReport, clean = TRUE)
          file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
        },
        
        contentType = 'application/pdf'
      )
      
    }
  )
)
```

R Sweave:

```
\documentclass{article}



\title{ Model Replication and Validation Report}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

<<setup, cache = FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(width=200)
setwd("C:/Users/mtorsan/Documents/APP")
@

<<Concstat,echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
options(digits=2)
@

\section{Regression Model}

Replication of the regression model:

<<Model,echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(comment="", message=FALSE,tidy.opts=list(keep.blank.line=TRUE, width.cutoff=120),options(width=100), cache=TRUE,fig.align='center',fig.height=6, fig.width=10,fig.path='figure/beamer-',fig.show='hold',size='footnotesize', cache=TRUE)

print(textReg())
print(Reg.model())

print(SummaryReg())
@

Conclusion of the model:

 AIC:
<<echo=FALSE>>=
print(aic())

@

VIF:

<<echo=FALSE>>=
print(VIF())

@

Parameters:
<<echo=FALSE>>=
print( Determination())
 
@

Adjusted R Squared:
<<Vif,echo=FALSE>>=


 print(AdjustedDetermination())
@

After replication, we begin the model validation, testing the assumptions of linear model.

\subsection{Normality of the residuals}

<<nor,echo=FALSE>>=

print(testanalitico2())
print( concprueba2())
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example? or what is your problem?.. the code is too long..

Comment: Please check my last questions, which are above with hyperlink. In the first one I posted a picture. I cannot provide more, other answer were to post all the code or a MRE. I do not know how to explain more than that!!!! You can copy and paste the code and run it :)

Comment: We can't copy the code and run it: it contains references to files that exist only on your own local machine.  For example `setwd("C:/Users/mtorsan/Documents/APP")`.  Any code that includes 19 `library` statements is very unlikely to be *minimal*.  As OP, it is your responsibility to help us to help you.  Refering us to previous questions is less than optimal.

Comment: I reduce the packages, I hope will be ok now. Regarding to working directory-the command exist in order to refer to the folder where the two files above are saved, no other file is involved, you can ignore that statement or to put your working directory were you will save this 2 files( r shiny code and rnw from sweave). It is also possible to run the code in RStudio Cloud and to just delete the command with ```setwd```.

Comment: ALSO the problem appear only when I generate the pdf report from R Shiny. When I posted pictures (in my fist  question-you have hyperlink) the answer was to put all the code. I uploaded all the code now, I think you can just click on the hyperlink and see the pictures there :) Thank you !!!!